# SimpleCookie load() not create an HTTP_COOKIE

Tags: python, http, cookies, httpcookie

I try to create an HTTP_COOKIE by data that i get from a HTTP response as string.

Here my code:

```
ck = SimpleCookie()
ck.load(cookie)
print("Cookie: " + cookie + "\nLoad: " + str(ck))
```

That works for many responses but not for all seemingly.

For example if

`cookie = 'MUID=12345678910111213141516; domain=.bing.com; expires=Sun, 20-Sep-2020 16:55:46 GMT; path=/;, MUIDB=16151413121110987654321; path=/; httponly; expires=Sun, 20-Sep-2020 16:55:46 GMT'`

than `print(str(ck))` is empty. I have edited the cookie values for this post.

Why is the SimpleCookie empty? I get that string from a valid http header cookie field.

Answer (score 1):

I encounter this problem as well and I found that this behavior is intended to avoid injection.

In your cookie, there's one key without value `httponly`. SimpleCookie will return an empty dict if this case.

See more at [issue37277](https://bugs.python.org/issue37277), [issue27828](https://bugs.python.org/issue27828), [issue22796](https://bugs.python.org/issue22796)